# What is the difference between 'caller' and 'base' workspace in matlab?

Tags: matlab, workspace

I know the 'base' means base workspace and 'caller' means functional workspace.

Any differences? plz give me an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper terminology is *function* and *base* workspace.

Here are the [definitions (including highlighting the differences)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/base-and-function-workspaces.html). The essential differene seems to be that base workspace is shared among all script- and command line- created variables, while function workspaces are created and destroyed (completely or partially) on each function's call.

Here are the [examples on manipulating the workspaces.](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_prog/share-data-between-workspaces.html)